# MVC Dynamic Views From Url Slug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am building my first .NET MVC web application and loving the simplicity and flexibility. I have however come to my first stumbling block.

I have a list of items and if you are not logged in you will see a preview link I would like the link to direct to something like below:

```
/preview/unique-slug
```

The view should then allow me to display the contents from the database (essentially a details page)

I am not sure how to approach this nor what I should be Google'ing as the results I got were poor.

Any pointers please?

Comment: Which bit are you having trouble with? Generating the URL? Responding to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I've done this in the past:

You need to store in the database a column with the slug that each item is referred to by. Then, create a route like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute("PreviewLink",
    "/preview/{slug}",
    new { controller = "Preview", action = "Details" }
);
```

So this will call the `Details` method on the `PreviewController` like so:

```
class PreviewController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(string slug)
    {
        var model = db.GetItemBySlug(slug);
        return View("Details", model);
    }
}
```

Basically, you'll get the slug as a string in your action method, query the database for the item with the corresponding slug, and display it. Essentially, we just replace an integer `id` with a string `slug`.

Hopefully that clears things up for you!